# Scope of OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have developed an application with the push service in which I am changing some preference on receiving a push and have written the preference change listener for that particular preference in my `onCreate()` function of main activity and register it like this :

```
static  OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listner;
SharedPreferences prefs;
```

// inside `onCreate`

```
prefs=getSharedPreferences(GCMIntentService.MY_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
listner=new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sp, String key) {
        //Here is my code    
}

prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listner);
```

I am confused about whether the listner will be called or not if my activity is not running or my application is closed.

Comment: Why you haven't tried testing yourself? Planting Log() in listener and changing something to see if it is triggered should not be that hard

Comment: I have tested it its not calling could you please suggest me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research and testing finally i have realized that the listener scope is till the application running or activity is in running state.

Once you closed your application your onPreferenceChangeListener will not be listen any event.

Might be helpful for others.

Anyway thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive notification on settings change no matter what is the Activity state, then I'd suggest to extend `Application` object and move your listener code there, as with activities you should register your listener in `onResume()` and unregister `onPause()`. So if user is away (which is the case as s/he launched preferences Activity) you will not get notifications.

Comment: Actually the task which i was performing on receiving of a push, instead of saving in preferences and calling listener i have written the code there itself in my IntentService now its working fine thanks.